# IOS Reading Appstore crash logs

Tags: swift, crash-reports

So I submitted an app to the apple store, they rejected it saying it was crashing on them, which I can't duplicate, they sent me a crash log file, but I am not 100% sure how to read it.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  tellall                        0x51c08 closure #1 in Dashboard.fetch() + 4336098312 (Dashboard.swift:4336098312)
1  tellall                        0x573bc thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed FIRQuerySnapshot?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 4336120764 (<compiler-generated>:4336120764)
2  tellall                        0x437090 std::__1::__function::__func<-[FIRQuery addSnapshotListenerInternalWithOptions:listener:]::$_0, std::__1::allocator<-[FIRQuery addSnapshotListenerInternalWithOptions:listener:]::$_0>, void (firebase::firestore::util::StatusOr<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>)>::operator()(firebase::firestore::util::StatusOr<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>&&) + 211 (FIRQuery.mm:211)
3  tellall                        0x4367cc firebase::firestore::core::EventListener<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>::Create(std::__1::function<void (firebase::firestore::util::StatusOr<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>)>)::CallbackEventListener::OnEvent(firebase::firestore::util::StatusOr<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>) + 33 (status_fwd.h:33)
4  tellall                        0x438038 void std::__1::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void, true>::__call<firebase::firestore::core::AsyncEventListener<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>::OnEvent(firebase::firestore::util::StatusOr<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>)::'lambda'()&>(firebase::firestore::core::AsyncEventListener<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>::OnEvent(firebase::firestore::util::StatusOr<firebase::firestore::core::ViewSnapshot>)::'lambda'()&) + 33 (status_fwd.h:33)
5  tellall                        0x5525e0 firebase::firestore::util::Task::ExecuteAndRelease() + 491 (function.h:491)
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x64780 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x10bdc _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1082c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 36
9  CoreFoundation                 0x91b1c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10 CoreFoundation                 0x757b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2080
11 CoreFoundation                 0x79e90 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 584
12 GraphicsServices               0x1998 GSEventRunModal + 160
13 UIKitCore                      0x370bb8 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
14 UIKitCore                      0x370830 UIApplicationMain + 312
15 libswiftUIKit.dylib            0x2addc UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 100
16 tellall                        0x8084 main + 4335796356 (Selection.swift:4335796356)
17 ???                            0x1e7a73344 (Missing)
```

I figured `+ 4336098312` is supposed to be an actual line, but there is only 600 lines of code in the Dashboard.swift file, so I don't even know where to start. Please if you can point me in the right direction or explain how to read this so I can find the line that is causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

This crashlog is indicating a problem with a closure in `Dashboard.swift` file's `fetch()` function.
The error message suggests that a closure may be trying to access an object that has already been deallocated or released from memory. Review the code that uses the closure and identify any objects that may have been incorrectly released or not retained properly (e.g. `self`).
Also, `+ 4336098312` is not supposed to be a line number.